# Linq to XML in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, nodes, nodevalue

IS there a way to use Linq to XML in .net 2.0? I'm not sure about it, if not, how could i recode this

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("config.xml");
var xVideo = doc
               .Element("XML")
               .Element("VIDEO");
xVideo.SetElementValue("MAPTEXTURELEVEL", 8);
doc.Save("config.xml");
```

Without using Linq to XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("config.xml");    
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/XML/VIDEO/MAPTEXTURELEVEL[1]");
node.InnerText = "8";
doc.Save("config.xml");
```

No, you can't use XDocument in .net 2.0