# How to achieve the below code in asp.net2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

Since i am using asp.net2.0 when i used the below class i am getting the following error.

```
Error 1 : The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The class i have used.How can i use this code in asp.net2.0 without getting any error

```
public static XElement GetGeocodingSearchResults(string address)
{
    // Use the Google Geocoding service to get information about the user-entered address
    // See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html for more info...
    var url = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?  
    address={0}&sensor=false", HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(address));

    // Load the XML into an XElement object (whee, LINQ to XML!)
    var results = XElement.Load(url);

    // Check the status
    var status =results.Element ("status").Value;
    if (status != "OK" && status != "ZERO_RESULTS")
        // Whoops, something else was wrong with the request...
        throw new ApplicationException("There was an error with Google's Geocoding Service: " + status);

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` is simply a [shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) for the actual type of the right-side expression.

```
public static XElement GetGeocodingSearchResults(string address)
{
    // Use the Google Geocoding service to get information about the user-entered address
    // See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html for more info...
    string url = String.Format("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false",
       HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(address));

    // Load the XML into an XElement object (whee, LINQ to XML!)
    XElement results = XElement.Load(url);

    // Check the status
    string status =results.Element ("status").Value;
    if (status != "OK" && status != "ZERO_RESULTS")
        // Whoops, something else was wrong with the request...
        throw new ApplicationException("There was an error with Google's Geocoding Service: " + status);

    return results;
}
```

**BUT** `LINQ to XML` (and whole `LINQ` functionality) is only available in .NET 3.5 and above. You should either upgrade to .NET 3.5 or [switch to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375038/linq-to-xml-in-net-2-0) `System.Xml`

Comment: I tried it but i am getting the following error in `XElement.Load(url)`.The error is as follows  `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: It would be extremely helpful for me if you could help me out in writing the above code in System.Xml format

Comment: Make sure you have `XElement results = XElement.Load(url);`, not `string results = XElement.Load(url);`

Comment: The error in your comment approves you have `.NET 3.5` installed. So, you don't have to switch to `System.Xml`. Please update the question with the exact code you have so far.

Comment: Yes you all were right.I have put some code in `Web.config` to make the compiler run in 3.5.The code is as follow                      `<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>      
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>`